# yii2 mpdf view displaying debug toolbar code

Tags: css, printing, yii2, mpdf

I'm using kartik mpdf extension to print a report. Problem is, in print view css code displaying and in footer debug toolbar code too. Please guide me how to remove that.
i'm using following code.

```
 $content = $this->render('print', ['modelPatientTest' => $modelPatientTest]);

        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, // leaner size using standard fonts
            'content' => $content,
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'options' => [
                'title' => 'Test Report',
            ],
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => [''],
                'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}|'],
            ]
        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
```

[image: See print screen here]

Answer (score 3):

As Debug toolbar should be active only in a development environment, put at the top of your controller's action this code:

```php
if(YII_DEBUG === true || YII_ENV === "dev") {
   Yii::$app->getModule('debug')->instance->allowedIPs = [];
}
```

(Edited thanks to @Gubberrr comment below)

Comment: This works fine in dev environement. 
In productionmode you could get a 'page not found' response.
In this case you can use
 `if(YII_DEBUG === true || YII_ENV === "dev") Yii::$app->getModule('debug')->instance->allowedIPs = [];`

Answer (score -2):

Just change

```
'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
```

to

```
 'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
```